# Something like a Navigation Controller for Android?

Tags: android, navigationcontroller

I'm new at Android Development but I have a good level at iOS/Java Development.

I would like to use something like a Navigation Controller to travel between views (activities, I know) in my Android app. What should I use ?

Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out old class android.app.TabActivity or new one which is called Fragment. At elast TabActivity should be available in most of IDEs.

Here is an example of tab activity:

```
public class TabbedActivity extends TabActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TasksActiveListActivity.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost   
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Tasks",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, StatisticActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Statistic",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);  


        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, PurchaseActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albumz").setIndicator("Bonuses",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);


        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }



}
```

Comment: Both are available with Eclipse, I'm gonna have a look to this. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Use fragment instead of old and deprecated TabActivity 
please Check out this Post: 
[Android UINavigationController-like feature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3251934/3187366)

Answer (score 0):

Intents are used for navigating between views/activities.Check [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: OP asked about UI element visible to user, not about the programmatic way to open new screen.